# Schedule running R Script

Tags: r, rjava, r-taskscheduler

I am trying to automate running a script (to be scheduled every 6 hours or so) which uploads a dataframe from `R` to `presto`. This requires connecting `R` to `presto`, which I have successfully established using the `dBI` package.

I have saved the R and Presto `JDBC` connection using `save.image` in a file and then tried to load it using `taskscheduleR`. But R throws the following error:

> Error in .jcall(conn@jc, "Ljava/sql/Statement;", "createStatement") : 
>     RcallMethod: attempt to call a method of a NULL object.

Could you please suggest how I can save the connection and schedule running the script every 6hrs?

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using and point out which line is erroring?

Comment: post a snapshot of your code to understand your issue.

Comment: Hi, the code runs successfully if I connect to Presto and upload the dataframe. The problem occurs when I save the environment, then close the Rstudio, restart R, load the workspace and run the script

Comment: Here is the code:                                                                                                                 data <- list()                                                                                                                        data['conn'] <- conn
save.image(list = ls(file = 'data.RData') load('data.RData')