# can't retrieve data using dbquery()

Tags: sql-server, rstudio

using this code to retrieve data from SQL server

`...data <- dbGetQuery(connection, paste0("SELECT * FROM ", "SCHEMA", ".", "TABLE_NAME"))..`.

and I got this error

> ...Error in .jcall(conn@jc, "Ljava/sql/Statement;", "createStatement")
>   :    RcallMethod: attempt to call a method of a NULL object...

Comment: What language are you using here @WinnieHolden? Is it rstudio or another language?

Comment: @Birel Yes - rstudio

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320001/schedule-running-r-script) @WinnieHolden. Look in the comments - I think that is how the code should be changed...